# Is it possible to place a string variable inside a Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is it possible to place a string variable inside a Regex? If so.. how?
I've been playing with regex for 4 hours now and i need just one more thing to finish.

```
return (new Regex(@"\bA=(\d+[/]\d+)").Match(From).Groups[1].Value.Trim()).ToString();
```

This line basically gets any fractional number like 42/13 only if it's after "A=" from a string and extracts it.
So here's my question - Is it possible to do something like that:

```
string variable;
Regex(@"\b"variable"=(\d+[/]\d+)").Match(From).Groups[1].Value.Trim()).ToString();
```

The idea is to make it so whatever is in variable becomes the regex and for example if in the variable we input D it's now D= now A=.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What is the X Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: You need to add `@` to each string and concatenate per usual: `@"\b" + variable + @"=(\d+/\d+)"`. You also don't need to encase `/` as `[/]`, just use it literally. Also note that you should escape your variable using the [`Regex.Escape()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It's just a string inside there, you can do something like `Regex($@"\b{variable}=(\d+[/]\d+)")`

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks man exactly what i was asking for and then some. And so fast too. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

This is string interpolation. You use the `$` operator on your strings to use it. Example

```
        string variable = "hello";
        Regex regex = new Regex($@"\b{Regex.Escape(variable)}=(\d+[/]\d+)");
```

Comment: I guess that works as well, thanks.

Comment: Regex.Escape(variable)

Comment: @MikaTähtinen updated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate your strings as usual (`+`) and prepend `@` to each string if using backslashes without escaping them. You also don't need to encase `/` in the character class as `[/]`. Alternatively, [as mentioned by Josh in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59534215/3600709) and Ron Beyer in his comment below your question, you can use interpolation.

```
@"\b" + variable + @"=(\d+/\d+)"
```

Additionally, you should use the method [`Regex.Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=netframework-4.8) against your variable to ensure any special characters are escaped (this will prevent your pattern from failing or making incorrect matches) - sanitizing your variable.

Comment: What if the variable contains regex constructs. `variable = '[AD]?';` on purprose.

Comment: @x15 that's why I mentioned that the OP should use the `Regex.Escape()` method. The last paragraph of my answer addresses this?